# Range as a function parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function that counts the number of cells in a range that have the same background as the reference one

```
function Color_Count (rango, color_cell) {
 var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
 var cell_colors = sheet.getRange('"' + rango + '"').getBackgroundColors();
 var color = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('"' + color_cell + '"').getBackgrounds();
 var count = 0;

 for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
   for(var c = 0; c < cell_colors[0].length; c++) {
     if(cell_colors[r][c] == color) {
       count = count + 1;
     }
   }
 }
    return count;
```

But I get the error that the range is not found. How could I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please include the parameters that you are passing to the function as well the textual error message. Ref. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the problem are the following expressions:

```
'"' + rango + '"'
```

and

```
'"' + color_cell + '"'
```

Assuming that `rango` and `color_cell` are strings and they are valid references, replace the above expressions by

```
rango
```

and by

```
color_cell
```

respectively. In other words, don't add the `"` when passing a cell reference as string as `getRange()` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: This is the file I'm working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykZjlgDJaszSFZih-144xIH_DDwboHtjjUvVydhxjfc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

#### Counting Background Colors that match a reference cell

```
function Color_Count(rango="A1:J1", color_cell="A2") {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell_colors = sh.getRange(rango).getBackgroundColors();
  var color = sh.getRange(color_cell).getBackground();
  var count = 0;
  cell_colors.forEach(r => {
    r.forEach(c => {if(c == color){count++}})
  });
  Logger.log(count);
  return count;
}

Execution log
10:20:18 AM Notice  Execution started
10:20:19 AM Info    5.0
10:20:20 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I need the range and the color_cell to be a parameter that I can input into the function, I do that, that won't happen

Comment: this is the file I'm working on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykZjlgDJaszSFZih-144xIH_DDwboHtjjUvVydhxjfc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The range and color cell are parameters.  Those are default values for Javascript parameters.  Here's a reference for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters),  Just for your interest we do expect that you are at least a student of javascript which means that you are at least looking at a Javascript reference while you are coding.